# How to delete data where inside the documents which are containing auto generated ID 's

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `google-cloud-firestore` as the database in my project what is belong  to `angular`. I used 
`import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';` for import the firestore. And I used this function for add data for the database.

```
changeLevelToSelect() {

  var student = {
    id: 1001,
    name: 'Tom',
    age: 22
  };

  this.firestore.collection('School').add(student);
}
```

This function is working. and I could have been able to attain this result
[image]

In this case I not use the `set()` method with a document name. Instead of I used `add()` function. Then there is no `document name` instead of there is a unique id numbers which are provided by the firestore. Now I'm in a trouble, That is how I delete or modify this data when I need. Because there is no document name for refer the documents. Can you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to delete or modify a document is using its ID.  You will either need to know that ID, or come up with a query that gives you documents that you can modify using their IDs.

Comment: How I find it. Is there any method for it

Comment: There is lot of methods to get the id of a document.Please refer the documentaton